# How to reduce a given number in a two digit number without recursion method in Java?

Tags: java

This is the problem I'm trying to solve. Given a number like 6928:

```
difference between 6 and 9 is 3
difference between 9 and 2 is 7
difference between 2 and 8 is 6
```

So, the reduced form is 376. Since this is not a two-digit number, we repeat the process:

```
difference between 3 and 7 is 4
difference between 7 and 6 is 1
```

The result is 41, which is a two digit number, and the solution!

This is an attempt using the recursion method, but I am looking to do it in a non-recursive way:

```
public static int twodigit(int value) {
    while (value > 99)
        value = reduce(value);
    return value;
}
private static int reduce(int value) {
    return (value<=9? 0:reduce(value/10)*10 + Math.abs(value/10%10-value%10));
}
```

Comment: Does your post have anything to do with C? Because I removed the tag in my suggested edit.

Comment: You need to use a couple of nested loops.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a couple of nested loops and some math to add and select digits.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(reduce(6928));
}

public static long reduce(long v) {
    while(v > 9) {
        System.out.println(v);
        long y = 0, factor = 1;
        // go through each digit from the bottom and calc the diff.
        while(v > 9) {
             y += factor * Math.abs(v % 10 - v / 10 % 10);
             v /= 10;
             // each digit is worth 10x the last.
             factor *= 10;
        }
        v = y;
    }
    return v;
}
```

prints

```
6928
376
41
3
```

Answer (score 1):

A tad more simple iterative method would be to convert the number into a string and pass it to below method

```
private static String calculateTwoDigitNumber(String number) {
    while (number.length() > 2) {
        String tmpNumber = "";
        for (int i = 1; i < number.length(); i++) {
            tmpNumber += Math
                    .abs(Integer.parseInt(number.charAt(i - 1) + "") - Integer.parseInt(number.charAt(i) + ""));
        }
        number = tmpNumber;
    }
    return number;
}
```

You can use StringBuilder instead of String if your input string is huge